# How to search in resource files in Eclipse? (escaped chars)

Tags: eclipse, resourcebundle

How do you search in resource files (*.properties) in Eclipse for string containing non-ASCII characters?

EDIT: Currently I use * in place of those special chars, but I'd prefer Eclipse to handle this for me: so it would either search for '\u00E1' in *raw files* when I enter 'á', or it might *translate* the files first and then just search for 'á'.

My apologize for not being specific enough when asking.

Comment: Do you mean searching within `Ctrl + Shift + R`?

Answer (score 9):

In Eclipse, you can use **Search** -> **File Search** . In the Search dialog, check the **Regular expression** option. Then enter this pattern in the **Containing text:** field to find non-ASCII characters:

```
[\u007f-\uffff]
```

(the square brackets are part of the pattern). Enter the **File name patterns**

```
*.properties
```

and then select which resources to search (selected resource, workspace, working set, etc.) and click **OK**

See also the [Pattern javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for how to express such regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I search them from the command line using grep, but you can search them in Eclipse by using a question mark in a non-regular-expression search, which should match any character.  You can also use a period in a regular expression search.

Answer (score 1):

The search dialog allows you to search for strings in *.resources files in the workspace.

Go to Search -> File. Enable the Regular Expressions checkbox - this also content assist to choose the regular expression according to your needs. In the file name patterns, give *.properties and then, Go :)